# Dynamically create/name a series of data.frames and bind them together

Tags: r, bind

I am doing a series of intricate data manipulations and in doing so I create a series of dataframes from one "source" dataframe and dynamically name all my "subset" dataframes.  They all have the same structure (columns) and I want to bind them together.

The challenge I have is that I can't seem to get the syntax for binding right after I dynamically name/create these dataframes.

So to create my "subset" dataframes I get the desired data into a dataframe called `df_master` and name it using `assign`.  I do this inside of a for loop so I end up with 10 subset dataframes.  Pseudo code looks like this:

```
for (i in 1:10){

    .... do some stuff ...

    master_df <- save into a df

    assign(paste0("df_months_", i), df_master)  # dynamically (re) name df_master

    }
```

This works fine and I get my 10 dataframes names `df_months_1`, `df_months_2` , etc.

The trouble comes in when I want to bind.   [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138693/rbind-multiple-data-sets#16140376) recommends binding multiple dataframes using `do.call`.  In order to do that I need to put my "subset" dataframes in a list and then use `do.call` and `rbind`.  This is the part I cant get right.  I think I need a list of the subset dataframes themselves.  But I can't seem to create that list.

Per the linked solution I need:

```
new_df <- do.call("rbind", list(df_months_1, df_months_2, ...)
```

Not sure how to create that list given that I am dynamically creating names.

Comment: Use `mget` -  `do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^df_months_\\d+$")))`

Comment: @akrun thanks for the quick reply.  Could you explain how that works a bit more?

Comment: I posted with some details as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we have create multiple objects in the global env (not recommended), check those objects in the global env with `ls` with a `regex` as `pattern`

```
ls(pattern = "^df_months_\\d+$")
```

It returns a `vector` of object names that matches the pattern - `df_months_` from the start (`^`) of the string followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string

Now, we `get` the values of the objects.  For `>=1` objects, use `mget` which returns a key/value pair as a named `list`.

```
mget(ls(pattern = "^df_months_\\d+$"))
```

Then, we use `rbind` within `do.call` to bind the elements of the `list`

```
do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^df_months_\\d+$")))
```

Comment: Would any changes be required if this were running in Shiny server?   I believe Shiny does not reference the global environment.  How would I specify for mget to look in the Shiny environment?

Comment: @Windstorm1981 Can you set the root directory `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "path/to/your/dir")`